# vertx authentication and session management

Tags: session, session-management, vert.x

I am using *Vert.x* in backend and *AngularJS* for my frontend.

*Vert.x* server receives HTTP actions using both POST and GET methods. Somehow I am getting different session ids for each request.

Following is the code snippet from my LoginFormHandler class handle routine.

```java
authProvider.authenticate(authInfo, res -> {
  if (res.succeeded()) {
    Session session = context.session();
    io.vertx.ext.auth.User user = res.result();
    session.put("user", user);
    req.response().setStatusCode(204).end("user Login success");
    //...
  }
//...
}
```

I am putting user object inside the current session. Then I move to new page and send a POST request to the *Vert.x* server. Inside that POST handler, I am trying to get the session object:

```java
Session session = context.session();
io.vertx.ext.auth.User user = session.get("user");
```

I am not getting the user. Also when I print session ID, I get different values for both sessions.

I have following code in start routine for the thread.

```java
router.route().handler(CookieHandler.create());
router.route().handler(
                SessionHandler.create(LocalSessionStore.create(vertx)));
AuthProvider ap = new MyAuthProvier();
router.route().handler(UserSessionHandler.create(ap));
AuthHandler basicAuthHandler = BasicAuthHandler.create(ap);
router.route("/Services/rest/user/auth").handler(MyFormLoginHandler.create(ap));
router.route("/Services/*").handler(basicAuthHandler);
```

Comment: What do you mean exactely by "*I am not getting the user.*". Are you getting a `null` object?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a new handler for authentication.

```
router.route("/Services/rest/user/auth").handler(new MyFormLoginHandler());
router.route("/Services/*").handler(basicAuthHandler);
```

Implement the handler as below

```
class MyFormLoginHandler implements Handler<RoutingContext> {
public void handle(RoutingContext routingContext) {

    HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.response();
    Session session = routingContext.session();

    routingContext.request().bodyHandler(new Handler<Buffer>() {
        public void handle(Buffer buf)
        {
            ....
            for (User u : users){
               if (u.getPassword().equals(passwd)){
                  session.put("user", u.getUserName());
                  response.setStatusCode(204).end("User Authenticated");
                  break;
               }
            }
        };
    });
}
```

}

Access the user from session.

```
class TestRequest implements Handler<RoutingContext> {
    public void handle(RoutingContext routingContext) {
        Session session = routingContext.session();
        routingContext.request().bodyHandler(new Handler<Buffer>() {
            public void handle(Buffer buf) {
                .....
                    String userName = session.get("user");
                .....
            };
        });
    }
}
```